# CombinedChart using wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, candlestick-chart

I am trying to use candlestick chart in react-native-chart-wrapper for a trading app, and i am using combinedchart from the example provided by react-native-chart-wrapper.And it is working in the case of xAxis{timeUnit:days} but i don't understand how to plot the chart in a time interval of 5 minute,15 minute,1 hour,1 day etc.

```
getIndexOfDay(day) {
 return moment(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD,hh:mm').diff(era, 'days');
}

{
  x: this.getIndexOfDay(moment.unix(e.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD,hh:mm')),
  shadowH: e.shadowH,
  shadowL:e.shadowL,
  open: e.open,
  close: e.close,
  date: this.getIndexOfDay(moment.unix(e.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD,hh:mm'))
 }
```

the above case is working, but

```
getIndexOfDay(day) {
 return moment(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD,hh:mm').diff(era, 'minutes');
}
```

this wont plot data on chart, i don't know how to set it correctly.
if somebody can , that will be a great help